# ESLint Error: prefer-arrow-callback on the reduce method?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm getting an the "prefer-arrow-method" eslint error thrown with the reduce function below. I know it's because the function is anonymous but  how would I rewrite the reduce method to resolve this error?

```
   const nameBrand =
     names.brand().reduce(function (sum, name) {
     sum[name] = name;
     return sum;
    }, {});
```

Comment: Replace `function(sum, name)` by `(sum, name)=>`

Comment: Did you have any look at http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback? There's no difference between `reduce` and any other function that is called with a callback.

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code IDE, it got light bulb which allow me to click and select auto fix this kind of warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const nameBrand = names.brand().reduce((sum, name) => {
    sum[name] = name;
    return sum;
}, {});
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find an example with the reduce method and I'm fairly new to JS.